# ZSH Killed my executable file in mac m1 while running the iOS project using script

Tags: macos, zsh, apple-silicon

ZSH Killed my executable file in mac m1 machine.

I am using the mac m1 machine to run my iOS project. Here while running the app it gets killing my executable script in the m1 machine.

I have fastlane, ruby to run the executable file.

In my mac /usr/local/bin has the following

[image]

In the /opt/homebrew/bin, it has the following

[image]

Also

```
zsh: killed
```

Comment: There is no question here to be answered. It is just a simple statement, with absolutely no detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin Edited my question, kindly let me know what are the needed inputs for this. I am new to this m1 machine.

Comment: We need enough information to run exactly the same things on our machines to see what happens and then debug it.

Comment: I have an iOS native project with the Automation executable file. To run the automation, it needs ruby and fastlane. So it will works. Before this it works fine without Fastlane. After setting the rvm and fastlane it failed to execute and ran up to some process.

Comment: Note: Previously brew is available in the two locations, /usr/local/ folder and /opt/homebrew. So I have removed the /usr/local brew and now using only via opt/homebrew

Comment: I uninstalled all homebrew packages.
Ran homebrew uninstall script to completely uninstall homebrew itself.
Reinstalled homebrew.
Reinstalled packages I want.
Installed zsh via homebrew.
ran `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`.
Opened new terminal.
Issue is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you have does not mean that `zsh` "killed your executable file" (which doesn't make sense), nor that `zsh` killed the running program (i.e. process).

Instead it means that the running process (the name of which is usually given right after the "zsh: killed" quote you list) received a KILL signal from the operating system.

You need to look at the processes you have instructed `zsh` to run in order to figure out why it received the KILL signal. Usually this comes from doing things such as for example try to start a program without a valid code signature, the out-of-memory handler in the operating system deciding that the process must be terminated, or that you specifically have some other process setup to actually terminate this particular process.

Comment: I have an executable automation for my iOS project, if I run the command to run the app, it killed the process.

zsh: killed     ./Automation

Comment: For me the valid identities are foind as expected xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning

Comment: Was it developed on the same computer? Does it fail like that if you run it manually from the Terminal?

Comment: And did you actually check the executable itself for code signatures?

Comment: Yes, in executables check for code signature